# Is there any relation between Process and Processor?

Tags: windows, cpu, process, threads

1 Process can have 1 or more threads.

1 or more threads (irrespective of which process they belong to) can run on 1 or more processors.

Is there any relation between Process and Processor? For example - only threads belonging to `x` process can use `y` processor?

Comment: [Processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity).

Answer (score 1):

The processor is a nickname for CPU, which stands for Central Processor Unit.
This chip is the heart of the computer, it runs all the basic calculations and decision making.

A Process is a thread that is spawned from a program with a sequence of instructions for the processor to execute.

A CPU can have multiple Processors and each Processor can have multiple threads. This basically means that a processor is capable of splitting its load into sub processors.

I hope this explains the relation between a process and processor.

It is possible to assign a specific thread for a specific process, but that't all there is in terms of correlation.

One side note though: Intel has performance cores and efficiency cores, the efficiency cores are slower, but the processor will inpect the load and use the slower cores for tasks that don't require a performance core, saving energy in the process.